# FILE IO buffering in C

Tags: c, buffering

I am exploring IO buffer implementation in C. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 / GCC.
Have a question on the way line buffering behaves and triggers underlying system call read(). My understanding on the line buffer implementation is that a system call to read() is done on encountering a new line in the stream. 
However, if you look at the first read() it reads 200 bytes. First write prints 114 chars before another read() is done, because a second write has a new line in the stream. 
However, if you look at subsequent reads() it doesn't look like it's triggered by a newline occurrence. 
It always reads 200 bytes irrespective of a new line being seen in the stream or not. On a side note, before the second read is done, there are about 90 chars in the stream already, how can it read additional 200 chars when the buffer size is 200.
NOTE: the output is exactly same if the buffering is changed from Line buffering to fully buffered in setvbuf. Can someone shed light on why is this behavior seen on how's line buffering supposed to trigger the underlying system call?

Here's the  code:

```
#define     KBUFFER         200
#define     LBUFFER         100


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *file;
    char lbuf[LBUFFER], kbuf[KBUFFER];

    if ((file = fopen("testing", "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Failed to open testing\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    // Set Line Buffer mode
    setvbuf(file, kbuf, _IOLBF, KBUFFER);

    while ( (fgets(lbuf, LBUFFER, file) != NULL ) ){
            printf("[%s]", lbuf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### #

Each line is 110 characters in testing;

Output with strace is:

```
open("testing", O_RDONLY)               = 3

read(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 200) = 200

fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0

mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7064a98000

write(1, "[aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"...,114[aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa][aaaaaaaaaaa
) = 114

write(1, "]", 1])   
                 = 1
read(3, "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\ncccccccccc"..., 200) = 200

write(1, "[bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"..., 114[bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb][bbbbbbbbbbb
) = 114

write(1, "][cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"...,  115][ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc][ccccccccccc
) = 115

write(1, "]", 1])                        = 1

read(3, "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"..., 200) = 200

write(1, "[ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"..., 114[ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd][ddddddddddd
) = 114

write(1, "][eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"..., 115][eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee][eeeeeeeeeee
) = 115

write(1, "]", 1])  
                  = 1
read(3, "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"..., 200) = 200

write(1, "[fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"..., 114[fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff][fffffffffff
) = 114

write(1, "][gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"..., 115][ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg][ggggggggggg
) = 115

write(1, "]", 1])                        = 1

read(3, "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"..., 200) = 88

write(1, "[hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"..., 114[hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh][hhhhhhhhhhh
) = 114

write(1, "]", 1])                        = 1

read(3, "", 200)                        = 0

exit_group(0)
```

#### #

Comment: This doesn't begin to make sense. You can't encounter a newline in the input *until* you call read. Line buffering on input is performed by the operating system, not by C. You are confusing it with line buffering on *output*, which causes a `flush()` on encountering a newline.

Answer (score 4):

> Have a question on the way line buffering behaves and triggers underlying system call read()

There is no concept of read buffering modes in the C standard library.

The C library reads into internal `FILE` buffer with `read` syscall when the data in the buffer cannot fulfil `fread/fgets/...` call. That read buffer exists only to minimize the number of `read` syscalls. `ungetc` came into existence probably to get more mileage out of that `FILE` buffer.

Line buffering and other buffering modes only apply to output streams.

Answer (score 1):

Line buffering is only allowed for output:

> The argument mode determines
>   how stream will be buffered, as follows: _IOFBF causes **input/output** to
>   be fully buffered; _IOLBF causes **output** to be line buffered; _IONBF
>   causes **input/output** to be unbuffered.

Some library implementations treat a specification of _IOLBF on input streams as equivalent to _IOFBF in practice, but this behavior is not specified in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` is using its own internal buffer to store data that it has read, but not yet returned (because it was on another line). It is free to make this buffer any size the author wishes. The only restriction is that it must not copy more that 200 bytes into *your* buffer.

I presume that the 200 byte read does match your buffer size as a deliberate optimization, but, again, the implementation is free to use any size; it makes no difference to your code.

You should **not** use any data you acquire this way to "optimize" your program as it is not portable and may change the next time you update your C library.

If the exact read/write sizes are important to you then you should bypass stdio completely and call the system calls yourself.

Finally, the line-buffering you refer to applies only to *output* streams, not input.